# UFD: existence of an infinite factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The definition of UFD requires that each non-unit, non-zero element to have a finite, unique factorization of irreducibles. But is it possible for a non-unit, non-zero element to also be a product of infinitely many non-unit elements? I would guess no since each of those non-unit element may be written as product of irreducibles, implying the original element being an infinite product of irreducibles. Am I right on this?

Comment: Without a topology, there is no meaningful way to multiply infinitely many elements of a ring.

Comment: In a UFD, if it's possible to factor an element into $n$ irreducibles and a unit, then any other factorization of that element will have at most $n$ non-unit components. 
On the other hand, plenty of non-UFD rings exist in which some element affords arbitrarily large factorizations.  For a minimal example, take any ring $R$, and consider the ring between $R$ and $T = R[X,X^{-1},Y]$ which is generated by all of the $Y/X^n$.  In this ring $X$ is not a unit and you have $Y = Y/X^n \prod_{i=1}^{n} X$, a factorization of $Y$ into $n+1$ non-units for any $n \geq 0 $.

Comment: Thank you Badam. It's a very good answer. But for non-UFD rings, is it possible for an element to have both an arbitrarily large factorization of non-units and a finite factorization of irreducibles--now that irreducibles are not necessarily prime?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question.  Do you mean for the element to be such that any factorization into irreducibles has length at most $n$ but there exist factorizations of that element into arbitrarily many non-units?

Comment: @Daniel Li Here's an infinite modification of the above example to think about:  consider the ring between $R$ and $T = R[X_1, X_1^{-1}, X_2, X_2^{-1}, \cdots]$ generated by all the $X_i/X_{i+1}^{n}$.  In this ring all of the $X_i$ are nonunits that have no irreducible factors.  You can tweak this construction to add in some irreducible elements in a controlled way.

Comment: It is possible for an element to be an arbitrarily long product of nonzero nonunits. For example, in the ring of algebraic integers, $2=(\sqrt{2}^2)=(\sqrt[4]{2})^4=\ldots $. But as Matt Samuel said, an infinite product is not defined unless some convergence is in play.